# usage of ajax in deleting a row

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a webpage that has several rows of data coming in mysql database. Im new to ajax i just try it right now, because of the reason that i want to delete row without refreshing the web page. I just want to ask if my code in ajax is correct or did I use it right. here is my code.

this is the generating of rows

```
            mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db("eis");
            $e=0;
            $d = mysql_query("select * from hrd_ot");   

            while($x=mysql_fetch_array($d)){
            $e++;
                print"<tr id='row".$e."'>
                <td>{$x['nam']}</td>
                <td>{$x['dep']}</td>
                <td>{$x['job']}</td>
                <td>{$x['dateofot']}</td>
                <td>{$x['frt']}</td>
                <td>{$x['tot']}</td>
                <td>{$x['toh']}</td>
                <td>{$x['app']}</td>
                <td><a href='#' onclick=\"return samplexx(".$x['id'].",row".$e.")\">OK</a></td>
                </tr>";}
```

and here is my ajax script | source http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

```
<script>
function samplexx(id,row)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
        row.style.display="none";
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","sample.php?id="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}   
</script>
```

and here is my sample.php

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("eis");

mysql_query("delete from hrd_ot where id='{$_GET['id']}'");
```

also it is possible the row that i've choose to delete will delete without using this line of code `row.style.display="none";`

Comment: Is your code working?

Comment: yes, at first when i dont put this code row.style.display="none"; the deleted row is remain but when I refresh i it disappear

Comment: Please show how you are calling the `samplexx()` function

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestions.

Instead of using the "GET" method you should use the DELETE method if you are following REST.

It wil be good if you can check for the status of the xmlHttpREquest.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
//hide row
}
```

row in your samplexx function is not a jquery reference to the selected row. So you should either use

```
$("#"+row).style.display="none".
```

or

```
 document.getElementById(row).style.display="none"
```

The below line just hides the row from the table. So that you dont have to refresh the page and fetch the new list of rows. Do this only if the server returned with 200 status.

```
$("#"+row).style.display="none";
```

Comment: Sir I think I must read first what is the use of .readyState==4 and .status==200

Comment: Sir can you explain what is 200 status?

Comment: Its the HTTP status code. Every response will have a status code.

eg:
200 success

404 not found

refer this link

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html